# Сочетание шрифтов левого бокового меню, центральной части и правого бокового меню

Tags: css, веб-программирование, вёрстка, шрифты, веб-дизайн

Есть сайт

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для левого бокового меню используется шрифт

```
font: 13px Roboto, Tachoma, Arial, sans-serif;
```

Для центральной части используется тот же шрифт. Для правого бокового меню используется шрифт `PTRootUIWebRegular`. Футер имеет вид

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите какие шрифты лучше всего подходят для каждой из частей сайта (приведенные шрифты плохо сочетаются как видно из скриншотов).

Comment: Во-первых, это вопрос про дизайн, а не про программирование. Во-вторых, вопрос слишком субъективный для этого сайта

Comment: @andreymal мне интересны любые идеи независимо от их субъективности, а на счет того, что это вопрос про дизайн, а не про программирование - так есть метка веб-дизайн

Comment: Если вы посмотрите вопросы по этой метке, то увидите, что большинство из них на самом деле про программирование. А вопросы, подразумевающие субъективный ответ, запрещены правилами сайта.

Comment: @andreymal а какие есть форумы по веб-дизайну из семейства stackoverflow (включая английскую версию)?

Comment: Теоретически можно расширить онтопик и здесь, однако это не отменит того, что субъективные вопросы запрещены во всём семействе stackoverflow

Comment: а что значит - расширить онтопик?

Comment: @programmerproblems SO не специализируется на вопросах дизайна. Да и точного ответа на такой вопрос вряд ли кто-то сможет дать.